# Select query for particular column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like the following.  How can I query this to join these two tables?  I need to implement this in one query.

Table1

```
 Id  name mark     
---  ---- ----   
1   name1 40    
2   name2 30   
3   name3 20  
4   name4 80
```

Table2

```
details_id    address userid  
----------    ------- ---
 1            A1      user=2
 2            dd      user=3
 3            gg      user=1
 4            kk      user=4
```

I need to join these tables using id and userid in both tables.

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.userid
```

Comment: Do you really have the text `user=2` stored in `Table2.userid`?  If you just have the number stored, then your current query does not look far off.

Comment: is the table2.`userid` field  varchar?

Comment: Assuming Table1 is the User Table and Table2 is the Details table, is the userId stored as "user=2" or "2" in Table2 and does it refer to Table1 column Id?

Comment: yes userid field is varchar,i know it is simple to join if i store the userid as integer, but i need to query this keeping user=1 user=3 etc in table field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT* 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 
        ON 'user=' + CAST(table1.id AS char(10)) = table2.userid
```

Alternatively, you could use a substring or something similar to remove the 'user=' and cast it as an integer for the join.

Comment: Be aware that any function (like cast and concatenation in the JOIN ON or WHERE clauses will disable the use of any indexing on those columns, so this will not perform very well without adding a function-based index on table1.id.

Comment: ok..is this the only method we can query this?any other way possible?is this a good approach to save userid in tables?

Comment: Sure, there are probably several other ways, but none of them get around the fundamental need to change both the data type and content of one or the other fields to get a match.  The answer to your last question is no: a properly designed database would have foreign keys constrained to the same content and data type.  If you don't have the ability to change this, you'll be forced to do some kind of workaround like the provided answer.

Comment: I have tried this and got syntax error in varchar(10) here--please help